# Hero transitioning with imported elements

Tags: polymer

So the hero animation transitions are not really documented very well anywhere I could find.

I can set up a page with hero-id on elements and have the transitions work fine, but can't get it to work if, for instance, my list of items lives in an imported  element. On the page swapping, I get an instant change with no transition.

Changing page back gives me a transition as it can obviously find the hero-id in the main html.

So really the question is: can I somehow link a hero-id in an imported sub-element with an element on my main page or another imported element?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages? That just went up yesterday.

Comment: I hadn't! Thanks for pointing that out. My hero elements are 2 levels deep from the core-animated-pages and that's what is stopping it from using scripted animations. Thanks again!